# WSAT (ASP.NET WebSite Administration Tool) is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I click WSAT (ASP.NET WebSite Administration Tool) icon, it doesn't open automatically, but I have to click on the dev server icon on system tray and open it up and it brings me WSAT with only a message:

> An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again.

Maybe this has to do with the URL it opens:

http://localhost:52785/asp.netwebadminfiles

I remember to see a longer URL sometime, like a URL having a query-string with "filepath" or "filedir" or something like this.

Can someone help me with this or indicate a tutorial to create my own user management on an MVC application?

Answer (score 2):

Since I had the same problem, here is what solved it for me:

first you need to run the project, and then run the website admin tool. That way it should work without problem, at least for me it did.